# Image flickers while swapping with another using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have 2 images which I want to show alternatively on page load. Below is the jsfiddle link for what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/8mMZn/

HTML:

```
<span class="solar-panel" title="Solar Panel"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.solar-panel {position:absolute;  left:280px; width:103px; height:83px;background:url(http://s28.postimg.org/q0ukhrf5l/solarpanel.png) no-repeat; }
span.solar-panel-grey {background:url(http://s16.postimg.org/5kik3yfm9/solarpanelshine.png) no-repeat;}
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    HomePageAnimation.panelShine();
});

var HomePageAnimation = {
    panelShine: function(){ 
        var index, timesRun, interval,solarPanel;
        index =0;
        timesRun = 0;
        solarPanel = $("span.solar-panel");
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            timesRun += 1;
            if(timesRun === 8){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            switch(index){
                case 0:
                    solarPanel.addClass("solar-panel-grey");
                    index = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    solarPanel.removeClass("solar-panel-grey");
                    index = 0;
                    break;
            }
        },600);     
    }

};
```

The 2 images used are 1) solarpanel.png and 2) solarpanelshine.png

On page load "solarpanel" is being shown. When you run the page for the first time, you will see that the first image "solarpanel" disappears/flickers once and then the image swap animation works fine.
When you again run this page, it will work just fine. If you clear cache ( am using chrome - Ctrl + F5) and run again, the first image will disappear/flicker again.
How can I avoid this?

And this only happens when the image is served from a server, it doesnt happen on local.

Comment: You can avoid it by preloading both images so that by the time the swap happens, the image is already loaded.

Comment: Can you please give me some pointers on how to do that? Also, just curious why is it happening. The first image "solarpanel" is already there on the page and what js code does is only overrides it with another image and removing same image for few cycles. So, why does the first image even disappears/flickers before the so called animation. Any idea?

Comment: I mean the swap of images from "solar panel" to "solarpanelshine" and the same cycle repeating few times

Comment: it flickers because when you change the class, all of a sudden the browser has to download the new image. While it is downloading, it shows nothing.

Comment: I have posted this answer below, with a jsFiddle for you to view how it works. The idea here is we're creating a reference to the images before everything else happens so that they are loaded into memory and then when you play your animation, it is ready to be rendered instead of being called and needing to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS images are only downloaded if they are being rendered on the page, so your second image isn't downloading until you change the class for the first time. I would cut them both into one image and toggle the background position rather than the background image URL. The technique is called CSS Sprites, and is good practice for performance, so worth trying out:

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks man, I will get it into a sprite, I believe its kind of pre loading only as suggested by Kevin in the response to my post.

Comment: Works perfectly now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to preload your image so it doesn't flicker.

http://jsfiddle.net/8mMZn/10/

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        console.log(this.src);
    });
}

$(window).load(function () {
    $(['http://s28.postimg.org/q0ukhrf5l/solarpanel.png','http://s16.postimg.org/5kik3yfm9/solarpanelshine.png']).preload();
HomePageAnimation.panelShine();
//rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I get it. I however found the sprite solution much easier and clean, so I implemented that, though both solution serve the same purpose.